# How do I serve an angular 2 app from django's development server?

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework

I have a project where I am using Angular2 to consume a rest API that I built with Django-Rest-Framework.  Currently I have to start up the django api using django development server e.g., 'python manage.py runserver' and then I have to start up the angular 2 server using either 'npm start' or through the cli, 'ng serve'.  Is there any way I can setup my django project to serve the angular2 project?

Comment: I answerd it here already: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43135009/6555866
Works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that Django-Rest-Framework has an option somewhere for serving static assets, right?

If that's true, you can configure the angular cli to produce its build output into a folder that Django is able to serve. The output of ng build is a bunch of static assets (js, css and index.html) that can be served by any web server.  So, if you change the `outDir` option in .angular-cli.json to point to your static asset folder in your Django setup, you can get the benefit of only having to run a single folder.

There are two main downsides of this approach. The first is that you now have to actively remember to run ng build everytime you update your angular project and want to see the new changes - you lose the automatic update and reload that happens when using ng serve.  The second downside is that ng build is noticeably slower than ng serve updating after changes are made (because the former has to write to the file system whereas the latter just keeps files in memory).

There are ways around having remember to do the `ng serve` on every save of an Angular file, but that either requires making use of gulp or grunt or another task runner to monitor for file changes and run a command, or making use of whatever functionality Django has for automatic file watching and reloading and figuring out how to hook into that (i'm not familiar with Django, but Rails had the `guard gem` to help with those types of setups).

I hope that helps.

(Honestly, I did a similar setup with Rails and ended up removing it and just running the two servers side by side - it was less stress that way).

Comment: Hey Snorkpete thanks for the reply.  Are you familiar at all with multi-tenant web applications? If you are i'd love to pick your brain sometime about it if you're able to.

Comment: meaning each user/account gets their own copy of the database?

Comment: Yeah sort of like that where a client signs up on my domain and they receive a sub-domain where their users can signup. Basically a shared database/separate schema or SaaS approach.

Comment: don't have too much experience with that, specifically, but i don't mind bouncing ideas around - i have a similar need myself - sent you an email

Comment: you can pass `--watch` arg to `ng build` to keep a watch on changes and update the code already built. :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Put the index.html file in the `templates/<project-name>` directory.

use this function to serve index.html which is the entry point to angular

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, template_name='<project-name>/index.html')
```

2. Put all your angular static files in the `STATICFILES_DIRS` so that they can be collected by `collectstatic` command.
3. Use `{{ STATIC_URL }}` in the path of your static files in index.html to access them

Now when you will access the index function your angular app will get served.

Comment: But what about the 'assets' folder ?, every single image url, response a 404 error...... What i am doing wrong? I have all files and folder builded from ng build --prod, and index.html down to 'templates/dist',. changes in index.html as well as {% static "bundles.js" %} are made...Any helps?

Comment: Compare the current images path in your html with the path you get from {{ static_url }}/assets/images/ then make the necessary changes. I recommend you to use s3 or google storage for images and other assets.